# Is the Query Store Parallelism the same as CX_Packet?

Tags: wait-types

I'm looking at the query store wait stats and getting high Parallelism wait type. Is this just a renamed CX_packet wait type?

Cheers

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all documented.

- [sys.query_store_wait_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#wait-categories-mapping-table)

> 16    Parallelism CXCONSUMER, CXPACKET, CXSYNC_CONSUMER, CXSYNC_PORT,
> EXCHANGE, HT%, BMP%, BP%

But of course, there’s nothing wrong with parallelism waits, and seeing them shouldn’t be a cause for concern.

Comment: Thanks Erik.......of course it depends how big the waits are and in this case they're causing the app to timeout. The server has default maxdop\threshold settings though

Comment: @AlexP012 no, CX waits won't cause timeouts, but do your thing.

Comment: Hi Erik I wouldn't normally be bothered about CX_Packet sort of waits but query store is giving me these stats for the offending query.

Parallelism 70 secs,
Idle                15 secs,
Buffer Latch 4 secs,
Unknown         0,
CPU                 1 secs,
Latch         0,
Memory         0,

 The application server is timing out after not receiving a reply from the SQL box in 30 seconds. The parallelism stat seems to high to ignore.

Why wouldn't waits for parallelism impact the app server timeout?

If you have time to answer let me know. I'm always looking to learn